# make -j4 zImage fail missing kdb_cmds reference

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, kernel, pi-3a+

I'm trying to recompile kernel on my **RPi3A**+.
Excecuting the following commands on clean Raspbian 9 (stretch):

```
sudo apt-get install openssl-dev
sudo apt-get install git 
sudo apt-get install bc
sudo apt-get install bison
sudo apt-get install flex
cd ~
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
cd ~/linux
KERNEL=kernel7
make bcm2709_defconfig
make -j4 zImage modules dtbs
```

After a loooong time I got this (sorry for the picture but I cannot capture it in another way):

[image: Error message]

Unluckly we had set italian as locale and we cannot revert to english at this time anyway:

```
kdb_main.c (xxx): riferimento non definito a "kdb_cmds"
```

translates in:

```
kdb_main.c (xxx): reference to "kdb_cmds" not found.
```

or something like this.

How can I fix this? I tried to google for `kdb` related compilation errors but it seems that it's never been reported.

Comment: `kdb_cmds` is an array used in `kdb_main.c` and also referenced in `kdb_private.h` but I'm not able to see where it's been declared. I have a strong suspect that it should be in `gen_kdb_cmds.c` but it's 0 byte long...

Comment: looks like it should be _generated_ by `Makefile` but running `make` into `kernel/debug/kdb/` has no effect (no rules ...)

Comment: You should make explicit all the steps you took from when you unpacked/installed the source to when you ran that `make` line, because there should be at least a couple.   Also, where you installed the source from.

Comment: @goldilocks I edited the message to depict the whole process.

Comment: Using the github source and `make bcm2709_defconfig` I was able to `make -j5 zImage; make -j5 modules; make -j5 dtbs`.  *This is a buster system though, not stretch.* There was one initial error involving `scripts/` that required `openssl-dev` installed, after that everything went fine although it took several hours (on a 3A+); the new kernel (4.19.80-v7+) boots and runs. It is odd that you say that screen hung there for a long time after only a few lines of output; normally there is always something going on up to the point where it fails or finishes.

Comment: No the screen/RPi didn't hung it worked for several time (I cannot say exactly how much but probably more than 1 hour) with a much longer output unluckly the RPi have been shutdown after that and before I could actually dump the error. But the message was the same of that second run. Is it possibile to reset `make` (`make clean` or somehting of this kind) and make the full process again?

Comment: yep also `openssl-dev` was missing and also I had to add this package, I forgot to put it in the history.

Comment: what's the difference between `j5` and `j4` option?

Comment: Nothing much.   It just tells `make` how many tasks it can begin in parallel.  A common heuristic is to use the number of processor cores +1.  *"Is it possibile to reset make (make clean or somehting of this kind) and make the full process again?"* -> `make distclean` https://www.kernel.org/doc/makehelp.txt <- You can get this via `make help` too; there are some options for setting verbosity/warning level during the build too.

Comment: Hi well ... `make clean` was just enough... I don't undestand why but after cleaning the system I got it working. Thnx for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly some previous aborted attempt is causing a problem, because this series of steps worked for me, although it took several hours on a 3B+.<sup>1</sup>  As `root`:

```
cd /usr/src
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
cd linux
make bcm2709_defconfig
make -j5 zImage
make -j5 modules
make -j5 dtbs
```

This actually did fail on the first attempt because some kind of helper script wants to build something that requires `apt install openssl-dev` (the error has an explicit reference to an openssl header being missing).  This is a bit weird as the vanilla kernel does not normally have any external dependencies besides libc.

I usually copy the kernel out manually; you can find that and the dtb/overlay stuff in `arch/arm/boot`:

```
cd arch/arm/boot
mv /boot/kernel7.img /boot/kernel7.img-dist
cp zImage /boot/kernel7-X.img
cp dts/*.dtb /boot/
cp dts/overlays/*.dtbo /boot/overlays/
```

And of course:

```
make INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 modules_install
```

After rebooting `uname -r` reports `4.19.80-v7+` and `lsmod` shows lots of stuff (indicating there are modules properly loaded).

If the build fails for some reason, you can try `make clean`, `make mrproper`, and/or `make distclean`; see [`make help` output](https://www.kernel.org/doc/makehelp.txt) for details.  If you use either of the last two, you may want to save your `.config` since that will be deleted.

**Note that this doesn't include firmware**; `make firmware` seems to do nothing.  However, it should be fine to use the stuff provided by the distro, since firmware does not need to match exactly the kernel it was built with (as modules do), nor is it affected by the specific configuration (including platform, since firmware is not compiled for that, ie., you use the same stuff on the Pi as you would an x86 desktop, although the Pi firmware package does I think contain some stuff not included with the vanilla kernel).

Also note that because the Pi uses a simple bootloader that looks for the kernel based on a singular name in `/boot`, **distro upgrades can overwrite your custom kernel**.  This is easy enough to avoid by giving the kernel a name that is not used by default (notice it was installed above as `kernel7-X.img`) and indicating that in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
kernel=kernel7-X.img
```

## Caveat!

Distro upgrades also install *and delete* directories in `/lib/modules` when rolling over the kernel. Point being, if the distro catches up to the version you are using, the module directory may be overwritten with modules that won't work with the running kernel.  Conversely, when the distro upgrades beyond the running kernel it may remove directories from `/lib/modules`.

Not having functional modules may be hard to notice because the default Pi kernel does not require any modules to boot and function normally to a great extent (including basic networking).

A way to avoid that is to compile the kernel with a custom tag that will then be used in labelling the module directory.  The default pi configs already do this, eg. `-v7`, which you will notice is used in the `/lib/module` directories.  Customize that via `make menuconfig` *General setup -> Local version* (in `.config` this is `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION`).  Note this tag has nothing to do with the kernel binary name (`kernel7-X.img` in this case). The version tag is compiled in and used to find the proper modules directory.

---

1. If the system is headless use `tmux` or `screen` in `ssh` so you can disconnect and leave it working.